# What is the Sunni justification for breaking the fast after sunset instead of after Maghrib?

Tags: sawm, shia-sunni, iftar

I've noticed a lot of my Sunni friends being very particular about breaking their fast immediately after it is sunset. As far as i know, it is makruh to wait a long time to break the fast, and that it is not wajib to break it immediately.

I'd like to know the Sunni justification for a couple of things:

- Why break the fast after sunset instead of after Maghrib?
- Why be so stringent about the time the fast is broken?

Answer (score 5):

It is sunnah to hasten the breaking of fast once the sun has set because Allah says in Qur'an:

> Then complete the fast until the night. **[[Surah Al-Baqarah
>   2:187]](http://quran.com/2/187/)**

The night begins when the sun sets. Therefore, when the person is overwhelmingly believes that the sun has set, then he has to hasten to break his fast.

> Narrated `Umar bin Al-Khattab: Allah's Apostle said, "When night falls
>   from this side and the day vanishes from this side and the sun sets,
>   then the fasting person should break his fast." **[[Al-Bukhari, Book
>   30, Hadith 61]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/61)**

On the authority of Sahl b. S'ad, may Allāh be pleased with him:

> "The Messenger of Allāh, prayers and peace upon him, said: 'People will
>   remain upon good as long as they break their fasts
>   quickly.'" **[[al-Bukhārī, Book 30, Hadith 64]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/64)**

**Source:** [Fasting Guide- Explanation of Shaykh Salih Al-Fawzaan](http://embodyislam.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/a-concise-study-guide-to-fasting-2nd-edition3.pdf)

Comment: hello, from the answer it is evident that the fast should be broken quickly. is it wajib to do so according to any saying/hadith?

Comment: @Nerrve As long as fiqh is concerned, it is not wajib. But, you will be deviating from Sunnah and following Sunnah is best loved by Allah.

Comment: ofc. Sunnah should be followed. i'm just looking for an honest opinion. there might be a reason it might not have been wajib. because Allah knows that it might not be always possible to break the fast exactly on time...

Answer (score 1):

In Islam every amal(deed) depends on niyat(intention).

If you intentionally delay the iftaar(breaking of fast by eating) then it considered wrong(against Sunnah).

Delay is permissible in following conditions

- We break fast (iftaar) and do sahri based on timings given in ramzan
  calander, but nobody can be sure of that timings to be 100% precise, 
  so if u delay iftaar by few minutes with the intention of being
  cautious about the accuracy of calander timings then there is no harm
  in doing so.
- there is only a few minutes difference in iftaar and maghrib
  timings,  and  it is better to perform salat as quickly as possible
  so with that intention if iftaar gets delayed then also  there is no
  harm.

Answer (score 0):

aoa i think now a days sunset is well determined. if you are standing on water at sea when sun sets in horison at the water level well that is true sunset. we must break fast at the that time. sunset in different months in different countries sure have a lot of light left over.

Comment: I suggest you to read: [How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)